# "===" is an unexpected token in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

Greetings fellow denizens of StackOverflow.  I am trying to write a react component which allows users to select a number (rating) from a drop down menu, which is then display and tracked persistently.  However, I have a small problem.  The computer doesn't like the "===" in my if statement.  It says its an "unexpected token."  What's the deal?  Here's the if statement and everything that comes before it since I assume you don't need the rest.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

 const loggedRatingVar = localStorage.getItem("rating0");

class DropDown0 extends Component {

 if (loggedRatingVar === null)
 {
  this.setState({displayRating: "?"});
 }
 else
 {
  this.setState({displayRating: loggedRatingVar});
 }
```

Comment: I think the issue is  that your class definition is wrong - you can't have code in the top level like that ... i.e. it should be in a class method - see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) - the code you posted is *sort of* equivalent to `DropDown0.prototype.if = function(loggedRatingVar === null) ...` in old school prototypal classes

Answer (score 2):

Classes are not functions. Classes are not executable.  Classes are CONTAINERS. They contain `constructors`, `methods` and `properties`.  Any code inside a class has to be inside a method or constructor.  (Well, the constructor is just a special method.)

This is basic JavaScript syntax and you'd do well to study the examples.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a class component not a function. 
I suggest to read the documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) on how to do it properly.
Since it seems you are setting states you would want to put that on a function or React lifecycle methods (more about lifecycle methods [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html))

Do it like so. Just gave an example on what Jaromanda X commented.

```
class DropDown0 extends Component {

    thisIsAfunction() {
        if (loggedRatingVar === null)
        {
            this.setState({displayRating: "?"});
        }
        else
        {
           this.setState({displayRating: loggedRatingVar});
        }
    }
 }
```